# if months in a range of cells is less than or equal to today's month then sum the given range

Tags: excel-formula

My table looks like this:

**Month**      No Of Flat

**Apr-13**     0.00

**May-13**     0.00

**Jun-13**     0.00

**Jul-13**     0.00

**Aug-13**     0.00

**Sep-13**     4.00

**Oct-13**     4.00

**Nov-13**     0.00

**Dec-13**     2.00

**Jan-14**     2.00

**Feb-14**     3.00

**Mar-14**     2.00

**Total**       17

Now what i want to do is add no of flats that are sold till today. i.e. answer should be: 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 4 + 4 + 0 + 2 + 2 = 12

I used this formula: =SUM(IF(MONTH(N149:N160)<=MONTH(NOW()), 1, 0)*O149:O160) as an array

but the answer I am getting is 2 which is just for this month i.e. Jan 2014.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use `SumProduct`. Try the following

[image]